# $\int\frac{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}{a^4\sin^2x+b^4\cos^2x}dx$

Tags: integration

$\int\frac{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}{a^4\sin^2x+b^4\cos^2x}dx$

---

My Try:
$\int\frac{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}{a^4\sin^2x+b^4\cos^2x}dx$
$\int\frac{a^2\tan^2x+b^2}{a^4\tan^2x+b^4}dx$
$\int\frac{1}{b^2}\frac{\frac{a^2}{b^2}\tan^2x+1}{\frac{a^4}{b^4}\tan^2x+1}dx$
I do not know how to solve it further.

Comment: Did you just make this up or found it somewhere? :o

Comment: It is given in my book.

Comment: This gives me motivation to attempt this.

Comment: Write it as $nr=a(dr)+b\frac{d}{dx}(dr)+c$ where nr is numerator dr is denominator and a,b,c are constants whose values are found out by comparing the equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrand can be written as $\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\left[1+\frac{2a^2b^2}{\left(a^4+b^4\right)+\left(b^4-a^4\right)\cos 2\theta}\right]$. It is easy from here.

Comment: how did you get this expression?@vnd

Comment: express the squared sines and cosines in terms of $\cos 2\theta$ and then simplify by dividing.